# Metro grid style

Tags: html, css, grid, masonry

I'm trying to achieve something like the following page:
https://undsgn.com/uncode/homepages/blog-metro/

I have tried and was able to come as close as this: https://jsfiddle.net/futu7t1c/

But how can I get those 2 `small-thumbs` at the bottom to move up?

The order is big, small, small, big, small, small

```
<div id="blog-posts">
<div class="grid big-thumb">
  Title
</div>
<div class="grid small-thumb">
  Title
</div>
<div class="grid small-thumb">
  Title
</div>
<div class="grid big-thumb">
  Title
</div>
<div class="grid small-thumb">
  Title
</div>
<div class="grid small-thumb">
  Title
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#blog-posts {
      -moz-column-count: 1;
      -webkit-column-count: 1;
      column-count: 1;
      -moz-column-gap: 0em;
      -webkit-column-gap: 0em;
      column-gap: 0em;
    }

    .grid {
      background: #eee;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .big-thumb {
      width: 50%;
      height: 600px;
      background: #aeaeae;
    }

    .small-thumb {
      width: 25%;
      height: 300px;
      background: #353535;
    }
```

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VWJGwz

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes, exactly (although, no white spaces). I see how you did this, but the content will be rendered dynamically in a loop so it's gonna be complex working with class="rows" etc, or not?

Comment: It shouldn't be complicated. It's consistent markup. What do you mean no white spaces? If you're referring to the white edge around the border, add `body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: No I meant the small images weren't big enough, but I solved it. Either way, your solution seems good but now my posts will load left column to right column which will make the 4th newest post appear on top right.. I want the news posts on top and then going all the way to the bottom if you know what I mean.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. What are news posts?

Comment: Submitted an answer. Please reply to my post if it doesn't work for you and make sure your post contains all of the details you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate that grid, you can make flex rows that have flex children that are also flex columns holding your images.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex row">
  <div class="flex col">
    <div class="big">
      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hNC-oT6f-fY/TeXxO26yjvI/AAAAAAAAAOY/qfkOqdKkBi8/s1600/platon-photographer-putin-man-of-the-year-portrait.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flex row">
      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="flex col">
    <div class="flex row">
      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="small">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big">
      <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hNC-oT6f-fY/TeXxO26yjvI/AAAAAAAAAOY/qfkOqdKkBi8/s1600/platon-photographer-putin-man-of-the-year-portrait.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Well, that's how you'd do it using regular ol' html/css. But since you want to just have a bunch of elements that automatagically lay out like that, use [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

```js
$('.masonry').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: '.small'
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.item {
  float: left;
}
.big {
  width: 50%;
}
.small {
  width: 25%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item big">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hNC-oT6f-fY/TeXxO26yjvI/AAAAAAAAAOY/qfkOqdKkBi8/s1600/platon-photographer-putin-man-of-the-year-portrait.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item small">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item small">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item big">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-hNC-oT6f-fY/TeXxO26yjvI/AAAAAAAAAOY/qfkOqdKkBi8/s1600/platon-photographer-putin-man-of-the-year-portrait.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item small">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item small">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is almost what you posted. Visually: yes; structure: no. If you look at the website I posted, the structure goes from left to right. Yours are two columns besides each other. So if I load my posts (Wordpress for example) I want the new posts on top. If I'd use your solution, it would have post 1,2 and 3 in the left column and in the right column 4, 5 and 6. I don't want it like that.

Comment: @Greg ah, be sure to articulate that in the post as it's relevant so people don't spend time writing code that won't work. They're using masonry to do that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry should have been more specific! It looks exactly how I wanted now, thanks! I will try it later on and then I'll come back to accept your answer, thanks

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I simply copied your code but I don't have the same result as you.. I tried it in jsfiddle and I get this https://jsfiddle.net/2ozatq8z/

Comment: Ok no wait, I forgot to add the jQuery part in the jsfiddle.. So there it works now, except not for my local project but I probably forgot to add something too

Comment: Ok it works, thanks! When using Wordpress I had to wrap the jQuery function in a `$(document).ready()` function to make it work